# How to smooth a edge (rounding) it

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm trying to learn how to smooth/round a edge of a model, currently I have a very simple case I can't achieve:
I created a sphere and cut it using the bisect tool, thats the result:

[image]

Now I'd like to round the top edge of this figure so it gets less shard, more rounded.

How can I achieve this? Tried selecting the top face and using the Bevel tool with no success =(.  (I'm a total beginner with blender) But it was near

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really get a large bevel there as it will overlap the preexisting geometry. Ideally you want very little geometry to begin with not just for performance, but because its much easier to work with.

[image: mockup of globe]

So here I make a mcuh simpler globe, but add a subsurfce modifier to take adding all the extra geometry out of my hands. Now I can double tap <kbd>g</kbd> to slide down the second to top loop, giving me space to bevel the top one. Like so.

[image: beveled globe with subsurf]

I then went ahead and removed that loop anyway as its pointless. This is the result.

[image: final version]

Obviously this bevel is much too large, but it illustrates the principle I hope.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use *Proportional Editing*.
Works well for dense geometry and doesn't require further subdivision.

1. Scale the top loop
2. Enable *Proportional editing*, set Falloff > Sharp
3. Adjust size as needed

[image]